# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called (again)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have already found the same question, but answers haven't helped me :(
Maybe because I have specific problem.
After installing app to iPhone 4S(iOS 5) some problems appear. I already fix couple of them, but this one more stubborn the it seems at first sight.

I opened existing Xcode3 project in Xcode4 and this problem appeared.

I will put some code here:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    // Return the number of sections.       
     return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [self.townShopsArray count];
}
```

I checked: self.townShopsArray is not empty

function:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ...
```

is not called, so I don't need to put its code here.

Can anyone tell me what could went wrong when I upgraded project from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4?

Comment: did you add the tableView delegate and datasource?

Comment: when I open .xib file and select tableview, then right click on it, I can see this: 
in outlets section:
- dataSource: File,s owner
- delegate: File's owner
in Referencing outlets:
- view:File's owner

does this mean that tableView's delegate and datasource is properly set?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the possible reasons:

- Your UITableView's data source isn't set to this controller
- Your UIViewController / UITableViewController's class is not set to the class of this view controller in the **Identity Inspector** of Interface Builder.  If this isn't set, iOS will ask the generic UITableView class for info about your cell, rather than the class you make.
  [image: Custom Class]
- (If you added the UITableView programmatically)... your pointer to the table isn't strong, and the UITableView has been deallocated

Comment: But it works fine in Xcode 3 / iOS 4 simulator and in Xcode 4 / iOS 5 simulator / iPhone4s doesn't. How is this possible?

Comment: And, I checked in debugger: datasource od tableView is set to this controller.
Second reason could be true, but I don't know how to check this (I said I am newbie:( )
tableView is added in ui builder

Comment: I think the Xcode version is probably a red herring.  Maybe a setting change.  Can you upload your Xcode project somewhere so we can take a look at it?  I'll update my answer for #2 with a picture of where this is set.